# Use property for calculation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, properties

specialists,

I have a document with several properties, one bein an lon/lat-array with a 2d index on it.
Another property is a radius property.

What I want:

```
{
geo:{
    $within: { $center: [[ 9.078597000000036,50.580947], 1+radius]}
}               
}
```

Is this available with mongodb? No matter what I am searching in google I am always directed to the mongodb documentation about geospatial indexes but my question is not getting answered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you, but the [docs page about geospatial indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/) give a an example of a query like yours:

```
db.places.find( { geo: { $centerSphere: [ [long,lat ] ,
                                    radius  ] } } )
```

searches places collection for everything withing `radius` distance (in radians) from the point `[long, lat]`.

Comment: What I really meant: The radius should be different for each document, so each document contains the radius that should be used for the calculation.

Comment: @Jan and you want to query for each document separately or all of them at the same time?

Comment: I want to query all documents at a time. My collection currently has ~500 documents each storing a property from 1 to 250 (km). I simply want to reference the radius property in my query. Currently I come to the point that it is not possible with mongodb.

Comment: @Jan yeah, you'll have to iterate your collection and query for each radius separately. Which means it's probably a good candidate for a m-r job.

Comment: Thanks :-) I now used the $near command and iterated the dbcursor an made the distance calculation by maself. The ordering is help enough, the rest is only little overhead!